# i want to create a layer with two different value of a field

Tags: attribute-table, fields-attributes, cursor

I want to create a layer with two different value of a field.

Suppose I have a layer named "Road Network". In that feature class i have a field in attribute table named "addi_rd"...

In this field there might have 5 different value. Those values can be 1,2,3,4 and .

So I want to create a layer only with 3 or 4 or both value other values are not acceptable..if 3 or 4 or both are found in "addi_rd" then code will create a layer with 3 or 4 or both otherewise it will execute next level.

Comment: What software are you using?

Answer (score 2):

in QGIS a quick way to achive this would be to first **select features by expression** and then create a new layer from the filtered selection.

**1.** Select features by value:

[image]

**2.** In this field put the expression `"addi_rd" = 3 OR "addi_rd" = 4`

[image]

**3.** Export the selection into a new file:

[image]